# What effects do multiple file extensions have?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I use Ruby on Rails and Uglify, which allows me to code in Coffeescript. So both of these file extensions are valid:

```
#1 file.coffee
#2 file.js.coffee
```

Would I be creating potential problems for myself by only using style #1? Is the .js necessary at any point from compiling to running on, for example, Heroku (or some other web server)?

I believe I read somewhere that Rails only looks at the last file extension and treats it accordingly. But I am wondering if there are any drawbacks to anything by not including `.js`.

Ultimately, what is the effect of multiple file extensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This convention is usually followed for Rails templates. Other examples are `.html.erb` and `.html.haml`. This conforms to the format `.[format].[builder]`. What you will notice is that these files will have a mixture of code. For instance, `.js.coffee` would have both Javascript and Coffeescript.

But ultimately, the `[format]` part of it is used to find the appropriate template to use and the `[builder]` part denotes which template processor to use.